# Setting char properties in Xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Perhaps it is something trivial but I am out of ideas...

Originally I wanted to add some features to PasswordBox. Because it is a sealed class, original properties have to be replicated, among them PasswordChar. Looks trivial, but when I started to set PasswordChar in Xaml, I could not get rid of parser exception.

At the end I simply defined a new property

```
public char MyProperty {get; set; }
```

and tried to set it in Xaml as follows:

```
<MyPasswordBox MaxLength="3" Password="xxx" MyProperty="c" />
```

I am getting an exception with the call stack looking like

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult()
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertStringToTypedCValue()
at MS.Internal.SilverlightTypeConverter.ConvertFrom()
at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ConvertValueToPropertyType()
....
at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetValueToProperty()
at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetPropertyAttribute()
....
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent()
....
```

As far I can read it, the type conversion string -> char fails.
Note that whenever I'll change the type of MyProperty to string (for example), everything works.

Does anybody know how to implement char properties so that they can be set from Xaml?

Working on **Windows Phone 7**, perhaps that's the problem. (Limited SVL 3)

Comment: Can you create a string property for XAML binding, and then a char property with a custom getter to expose the value as char to the rest of the code?

Comment: Don't know how you mean that. I'll probably define string-type property that will make sure that only 1-char strings are used.

Comment: By looking into SVL code it appears that they use special dependency property type. My guess is that this property adds string->char conversion to the xml parser. (See the callstack above) Most probably the rest of the world cannot use char properties in Xaml.

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify this will work, but you can give it a go. The long form xaml syntax should work ok.

Add the following to your namespace imports

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then the following should work

```
<MyPasswordBox MaxLength="3" Password="xxx">
    <MyPasswordBox.MyProperty>
        <sys:Char>c</sys:Char>
    </MyPasswordBox.MyProperty>
</MyPasswordBox>
```

The other solution is to look into type converters to apply to your property so that it'll convert the string for you. [Type Convereters and XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx).

Comment: Did it. "XamlParseException: Unknown element: Char". Setting password with "<system:String>c</system:String>" works like charm.

Comment: P.S. Even if it worked I would stil like to know why PasswordBox allows property attribute syntax for char property.

Comment: Of course, the property I started with (PasswordChar) is a DependencyProperty. Only subsequently I realized that the inability to set char values can be easier demostrated on a simple CLR property.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to double check.